# Integral points on a circle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Given radius $r$ which is an integer and center $(0,0)$, find the number of integral points on the circumference of the circle.

Comment: Tried Schinzel Circle and also tried the link below
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleLatticePoints.html

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for solutions to $m^2 + n^2 = r^2$ for a given $r$.  Clearly $(\pm r, 0), (0, \pm r)$ are four solutions. For others, this is equivalent to finding Pythagorean triples with the same hypotenuse.  You should be able to find a lot of references on this online.

In fact you can derive that, if the prime factorisation of $r = 2^a \prod p_i^{b_i} \prod q_j^{c_j}$ where $p_i \equiv 1\pmod 4$ and $q_i \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then $f(r) =\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\prod (2b_i + 1) - 1 \right)$ is the number of such triplets.

Each such triple has corresponding solutions in the other three quadrants, so in total we have $4f(r)+4$ integer points on the circle.

Comment: what is ai in the formula ?

Comment: Corrected it.  It is the exponent of the primes of form $4k+1$

Comment: From my experience, the correct formula is $f(r^2) =\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\prod (2b_i + 1) - 1 \right)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: hunt for Pythagorean triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$R^2= a^2 +b^2$$

Then the **Number of integral points** is the number of integral solutions for $(a,b)$

For example if $R=5$
Then $$(a,b)=(0,±5) ,(±5,0), (±3,±4)  $$

Hence number of points are 8.

A **Simple Algorithm** for this is:

```
for(i=0,i<=R;i++)   
{   
    for(j=0;j<=R;j++)
    {
        if(R*R==i*i+j*j)
         count++;
    }
}
```

This has **10^12 computations** if R=10^6

Rather than this an **Optimised approach** is:

```
for(i=0,i<=R;i++)
{   
    if(sqrt(R*R-i*i) is an integer)
     count++;   
}
```

This has **10^6 computations** if R=10^6 which takes **only 0.1 seconds** on an ordinary machine. 
You can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796983/checking-if-float-is-an-integer) for checking if a float is an integer.

Comment: suppose if have r=10^6 , i have to traverse a and b through 0 - 10^6. This is navie approach , can you tell me the optimised approach

Comment: And what about $(\pm 4, \pm 3)$?

Comment: The optimized approach has been added to the answer.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29644/enumerating-ways-to-decompose-an-integer-into-the-sum-of-two-squares.

Comment: What if $R=10^{10^6}$?