# Pythagorean triples for a given hypotenuse

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a deterministic method for generating all of the Pythagorean triples {a, b, c} for a given hypotenuse c?

Comment: The answer to your question as stated is trivially "yes": Given hypotenuse $c$, check, for each natural $a<c$, whether $c^2-a^2$ is a perfect square. Were you looking for an *efficient* deterministic algorithm?

Comment: @abiessu "Pythagorean triples" are integral by definition.

Comment: Are you familiar with [the theorem about which integers can be represented as the sum of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)?

Comment: Check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518856/integral-points-on-a-circle/518944#518944